# angular routeProvider recognize '%2F' but not '/' in url

Tags: angularjs, url-routing, ngroute

given the following routes:

```
        when('/contactus', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/contactus.html'
        }).
        when('/unsubscribe/:email', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/unsubscribe.html'
        }).
        when('/users/validate?key', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/uservalidation.html'
        })
```

After I started this application by

```
npm start
```

In browser address bar, if I put:

```
localhost/contactus <- GET /contactus 200
localhost/unsubscribe/abc <- GET /unsubscribe/abc 404
localhost/unsubscribe%2Fabc <- GET /unsubscribe%2Fabc 200
localhost/users/validate?key=1 <- GET /users/validate?key=1 404
localhost/users%2Fvalidate?key=1 <- GET /users%2Fvalidate?key=1 404
localhost/users%2Fvalidate%3Fkey%3D1 <- GET /users%2Fvalidate%3Fkey%3D1 404
```

so my questions are:
1) how to make the /users/validate?key=1 work?
2) Is it a way to not use url encoding? With the encoding, the browser converts `/unsubscribe%2Fabc` to `/unsubscribe/abc` which is expected, but refresh the page or copay and paste this url will not work again as it is again using '/' instead of the encoding value.

Comment: this maybe be useless for you, but i would recommend you to use `ui-router` this library extends ngRouter, and have the type of params in query that you want. Also nested views

Comment: Assuming you've set `$locationProvider.html5Mode`, have you configured URL rewriting on the server-side?

Comment: @Phil can you be more specific? I was assuming you are talking about base bref="/"

Comment: please [read this](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/).

Answer (score 0):

```
 app.config([
'$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',
function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    }).hashPrefix('!');
    var viewBase = '/app/views/';
    $routeProvider         
   .when('/admin/home/appliedlist/:userid1/:userid2/:userid3', { // For appliedlist page 
        templateUrl: viewBase + 'EditAppliedList.html',
        controller: 'EditController'
    })
    .otherwise({   // This is when any route not matched => error
        templateUrl: viewBase + 'Error.html'           
    })
}]);
```

for get url data

```
   app.controller('EditController', ['$scope',  '$routeParams', function   ($scope, $routeParams) {    
    $scope.Type = $routeParams.userid3;
     $scope.Name = $routeParams.userid2;
     $scope.ID = $routeParams.userid1;
}]);
```

and passing data to url

```
 <a href="/admin/home/appliedlist/12/pravin/employee">Edit</a>
```

Also you can encoding and decoding data using like

```
  <a href="/admin/home/appliedlist/12/pravin/{{MyencodingLogic(employee)}}">Edit</a>
```

put encoding code in function 'MyencodingLogic'

and decoding code use inside EditController where you get value through $routeParams

Comment: I guess you are talking about my question1? I would want the url to use query string such as validate?key=1&identifier=2 which is different from the route param that your code presented for.

Answer (score 0):

Just so everyone else running into this problem:

The solution I did is to change the server as Phil mentioned in the comment.

My server-side is node, which had:

```
app.get('/:page', callback);
```

and all I did is to change this to:

```
app.get('/*', callback);
```

And this solution fixes both of my questions.